# foward slash - use runtime optimize XPages

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, xpages-ssjs

when I use the compression JS/CSS parameter XPages IE8 browser don't resolve this resource (error 404)

```
/webhelpdesk.nsf/xsp/.ibmmodres/.css/bootstrap%2Fcss%2Fxsp-core.css&amp;bootstrap%2Fcss%2Fbootstrap.min.css&amp;bootstrap%2Fcss%2Fbootstrap-theme.min.css&amp;bootstrap%2Fcss%2Fdbootstrap.css&amp;bootstrap%2Fcss%2Fxsp-mixin.css&amp;bootstrap%2Fcss%2Fxsp-ie11.css&amp;basebs.css&amp;toastr.min.css&amp;contenzioso.css&amp;workflow.css
```

I rembember a NOTES.INI parameter for fix the encoding from %2F to /

Someone remeber?
There is not any reverse proxy before Domino

The release is 9.0.1FP3

Thank!

Comment: Re-reading your question, in URL the %2F is by default translated by Domino to / so your don't have anything to do. Did you put the whole URL you have in your browser and gotten and answer?

Comment: concertning the NOTES.INI what you wrote make me remember the SHELL_LINKS=1 but it's not slash related...

Comment: Maybe are you remembering the redirection rules that were advised to add to increase the security.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution?